# 'cameraView.addFrameProcessor' but using realtime image from the screen instead of the Camera

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been looking for days on google, but I guess I'm out of luck.

I'm looking for similar functionality to `cameraView.addFrameProcessor` but using real-time onscreen images instead of the camera. basically, I want to implement a feature similar to Google Assistant feature "Google lens" or "What's on my screen",

below the example for frameProcessor:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Fritz.configure(this)

        cameraView.addFrameProcessor { frame ->
             //This returns a frame, which cann be used to retrieve the preview                    
        }
    }  
}
```

Is this even exist?

Comment: Not sure how this question relates to 'ios', 'flutter' or even 'kotlin' tags. I would also clarify which `FrameProcessor` you are referring to as it is a common name in many libraries.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've changed the title and tags to be more specific.

Comment: I'm also adding some code example I'm referring to. @MorrisonChang

Comment: Are you aware of the [Android - MediaProjection API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection) For sample see: https://github.com/android/media-samples/tree/main/ScreenCapture

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks! I'll try this one, I'm not sure if this method is suitable or the best practice for my needs, I need to fetch the screen data as long as the display is turned on but I don't need to save the image file, this might take a lot of device resources for processing? or is there a way to intercept the screen data instead of doing screenshot hundreds of time? as I'm not really sure how this works on low level process.

Comment: From what I recall, the "what's on my screen" type feature only processed a static image so you are correct that multiple images would have additional cost. I would advise learning about image processing as it seems like you think that video would make it easier (short answer - it doesn't).

Comment: how about google lens? as it is real-time and running constantly, is there an alternative to that? but instead of using a camera, the image source is from the screen, is `MediaProjection` still the recommended way to do it?  @MorrisonChang

Comment: Google lens is a foreground camera app, which is free to use all the resources (like a game). The "what's on my screen" feature could have a browser or other app running. This will additionally have security permissions implications. Good luck.